# Is there any way to convert a char type into an int?

Tags: c++, vector, char

I want to add two large numbers in C++ using vectors. However, I can't find any way in which I could properly read them from a file, so I wanted to use a char array which will read the characters and, if they are digits convert them into an int variable of the vector.
 Is there any way in which I could do this?

Comment: You mean like converting char '0' to number 0 and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily convert digits into the corresponding integer values, because `char` can be treated as numeric values. Assuming you got some input like

```
char input = getNextDigit();
```

You can do

```
int asInt = input - '0';
```

which works, if `input` is any digit from '0' to '9'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [atoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) function. The given link has pretty clear examples on how to use it.

I hope this is what you were looking for!

**UPD**: whenever you deal with strings it is better to go one step up in terms of abstraction and don't work with arrays of `char` directly. `std::string` should be your first choice. Starting from C++11 `atoi` has an `std::string` version called [stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Wouldn't [stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) be a better choice in this century?

Comment: You are right, it is better to deal with std::strings than with raw C strings. I will edit my answer to incorporate this info as well

Comment: Relevance dependent entirely on the ambiguity factor of the OP's stated "two **large** numbers". Somehow, I have a feeling a platform `int` isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, but the question itself asks specifically for `int`.